# What is the most efficient and robust way for dealing with images when a SOAP web service is involved?

Tags: android, web-services, image, soap

I have an android application, that will call a SOAP web service for some data.

For the purpose of this question, we'll assume its data about cars.

I've got as far as returning text data about the car (make, model etc), that is the easy part. I'd also like to return an image of the car some how.

So far, I see two viable options :

1. Retrieve the image in the SOAP response (don't even know if this is
   possible)
2. Retrieve a URL in the SOAP response that points to the image,
   perhaps a URL to a web image

Could anyone please give advice as to what is a robust solution for achieving this?

Thanks

Comment: embedding binary content in SOAP, i.e. in the XML usually means BASE64-encoding the whole shebang, making your page less responsive (reading a huge binary blob before a "car" is properly parsed and ready for presentation etc. etc.) - you can of course [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments#SOAPReferenceToAttachements) it, but that's pretty messy also.In short .. use URLs.

Comment: @Jens thanks for the insight, I'll stick with URLs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2, definitely. If you do option 1, you're limited to displaying only after you've completely downloaded the entire message, including the encoded images. That can take a while. On the other hand, if you just include URLs, you can download the message, render your UI, then download the images and update those image views dynamically as the images finish fetching from the web. This results in a much more responsive UI, especially in a mobile environment where your data connection may not be as fast or reliable.

Comment: in fairness, one can reference content in XML that's bundled in a multi-part and still be snappy, but implementation-wise it's still sucky - the time won for those few extra HTTP requests on a properly configured HTTP connection with keep-alive isn't going to make or break any sensible app anyway (unless you need to do freaky stuff like signing the entire XML message + images..).